# Submitting Form Django Bootstrap Toolkit

Tags: python, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm utilizing the Django Bootstrap Toolkit for styling my website and have run into a slight issue. I am trying to have a form embedded within my base HTML that is essentially a user switch, whereby given a list of names, the user can decide whether he or she wants to switch users while utilizing the site rather than be logged in as "Guest" (the site is internal, so there's no real need for credential authentication). The views I have are such:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

import datetime

myUsers = ['User A', 'User B', 'User C', 'User D', 'User E', 'Guest']

def index(request):
    # make login default guest if not logged in
    if not 'myUser' in request.session:
        request.session['myUser'] = 'Guest'
    # grab user if we've submitted login form from this page
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'myUser' in request.POST:
            request.session['myUser'] = request.POST['myUser']
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', {'myUsers': myUsers})

def login(request, myUser):
    request.session['myUser'] = myUser
    return redirect('index')
```

The base HTML template that contains the form is the following:

```
{% load bootstrap_toolkit %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    {% bootstrap_javascript_tag %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block header %}
        <h3 style="font-family: Source Sans Pro, Myriad Pro; font-size: 16px; margin-left: 20px">
        {% if request.session.myUser %}
            Current User: {{ request.session.myUser}}
            <div class="navbar">
                <form class="navbar-form pull-left" action="" method="post" id="myUser">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <select name id class="form-control" style="width: 200px;">
                        {% for myUser in myUsers %}
                            <option value="{{ myUser }}">{{ myUser }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <button id="formSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Change User</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            No User Logged In
            <div class="navbar">
                <form class="navbar-form pull-left" action="" method="post" id="myUser">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <select name id class="form-control" style="width: 200px;">
                        {% for myUser in myUsers %}
                            <option value="{{ myUser }}">{{ myUser }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <button id="formSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        </h3>
    {% endblock %}
    <hr>
    <h1 style="text-align:center; font-family: Myriad Pro; font-size: 60px; padding: 10px">MySite</h1>
    <div style="text-align:center" name="content">
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    {% block footer %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

I get default Guest login, which is not a problem, but I do not unfortunately get any kind of user switching when the user clicks on the dropdown menu and selects another individual. It is likely I am missing something, but I unfortunately have been unable to figure it out if so. Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the following, `<select name id class="form-control" style="width: 200px;">`

You haven't specified the name of your `<select></select>` form field.

Simply modify your code to include the proper form field name.

```
<select name="myUser" class="form-control" style="width: 200px;">
```

Note that its highly recommended that you use a Django Form to process the form data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Though I made the suggested change, it unfortunately did not result in any changed functionality; I still get always Guest logged in rather than any of the other dropdown choices.

Comment: I take that back; I had modified the incorrect part; my apologies! Thank you very much for your assistance, that was terrific.